# Heroku, providing a deb dependency to Go project through APT buildpack does not work out

Tags: go, heroku, debian, buildpack

I have a PDF conversion package in my Go project which relies upon "wkhtmltox" debian package. I install "wkhtmltopdf" (similar to "wkhtmltox") through APT buildpack before running a Go buildpack. The "wkhtmltopdf" has been tested locally, and in this case Go project builds perfectly. But when I do it in Heroku, it does not work out, and fails with the same error as would pop out in case no "wkhtmltox" nor "wkhtmltopdf" was installed. The successfully installed "wkhtmltopdf" :

`remote: -----> Installing wkhtmltopdf_0.12.5-1build1_amd64.deb`

The error :

```
remote: ../codon/tmp/cache/go-path/pkg/mod/github.com/adrg/go-wkhtmltopdf@v0.2.2/converter.go:7:10: fatal error: wkhtmltox/pdf.h: No such file or directory
remote:     7 | #include <wkhtmltox/pdf.h>
remote:       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: compilation terminated.
```

Is there someone with similar experience ? Is it possible that for Go the installed package is simply not available without some additional manipulations ?

Comment: That package doesn't seem to ship any development headers, just binaries: https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/amd64/wkhtmltopdf/filelist . Maybe you cloned project repo with headers/installed source packages locally?

Comment: Thank you! Looks like the MacOS-targeted package content, that I installed through homebrew, indeed differs, and this is why it worked out in my development environment. I'll probably ditch the go buildpack entirely in favor of Docker which will give me more control. There are lots of custom buildpacks that enable to run arbitrary commands, but they most probably can't execute commands that require superuser privilege.